# Error: No named parameter with the name 'controller'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying running a code in Android Studio, but always I run the code, get this error:

Error: No named parameter with the name 'controller'.

```
TextEditingController nota1Controller = TextEditingController();
```

```
nota1Controller.text = "";
```

```
double nota1 = double.parse(nota1Controller.text);
```

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Nota 1",
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
    controller: nota1Controller,// <-- HERE IT'S THE "CONTROLLER"
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 25.0),
),
```

I navigate in a lot of sites, but I can't find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign controller directly to the TextField.

Eg:

```
TextField(
      controller: nota1Controller,//<-- HERE IT'S THE "CONTROLLER"
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Nota 1",
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 25.0),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the controller inside the decoration, simply put it outside it:

change this:

```
  TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Nota 1",
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
    controller: nota1Controller, <-- HERE IT'S THE "CONTROLLER"
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 25.0),
),
```

to this :

```
    TextField(
 controller: nota1Controller,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Nota 1",
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
   
  ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 25.0),
),
```